# What are “formules à volonté”?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

In French, I read a couple of times this expression, what does it mean? 
“formules *à volonté*”?

Comment: The literal translation of *à volonté* is "at will", here a eat-at-will menu. A more common expression using it in both languages is *feu à volonté*: "fire at will".

Answer (score 6):

It is basically a meal plan where you can reorder as much as you care. It is not exactly the typical "all-you-can-eat" as a "formule" is not necessarily a buffet. In France, some restaurants will offer this for instance with meals such as a "fondue bourguignonne", a "raclette" or mussels.

Comment: It is exactly "all you can eat". "All you can eat" doesn't have to be a buffet either.