# Un équivalent de « all-you-can-eat buffet » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, alimentation

Dans une autre question on a déjà traité des [*formules à volonté*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/29187) en restauration où l'on peut *commander autant de fois qu'on le désire*. Mais quand il s'agit exactement d'un *[all-you-can-eat](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all-you-can-eat) [buffet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffet)*, et non pas d'un [bar à salades](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364952) ou d'un [bar de salades à volonté](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=ALL%20YOU%20CAN%20EAT&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) par exemple, c'est-à-dire que l'on se sert soi-même, est-ce que l'on emploie le mot [buffet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/buffet) (par métonymie) et le cas échéant est-ce désigné par [*buffet à volonté*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_volont%C3%A9) ou autrement et emploie-t-on les guillemets à quelque part ([buffet « à volonté »](https://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/consommation/201902/15/01-5214847-les-consommateurs-grands-responsables-du-gaspillage.php)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- La formule largement la plus courante est **à volonté**, déjà proposée par Rémi Henry, elle n'a pas besoin de guillemets :

> [Les meilleurs restaurants Buffet à volonté à Paris](https://www.lafourchette.com/restaurant+buffet-a-volonte+paris)

[image]
[image]

---

- Il existe une variante plus soutenue, **à [discrétion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/discr%C3%A9tion)** qui sous entend une consommation raisonnable de la nourriture ou boisson proposée :

> *À discrétion. Comme on veut, autant qu'on veut. Boire, manger à discrétion; vin à discrétion.* Synon. *à son gré, à volonté. J'avais le pain, le jambon et la bière à discrétion* (Ambrière, *Gdes vac.*, 1946, p. 144).

Courante en Suisse romande, elle est aussi utilisée telle qu'elle en Suisse alémanique.

[image]

---

- A l'opposé, on trouve l'expression familière et ancienne, **[à gogo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_gogo)** (à profusion) déjà référencée dans le [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/gogo).

[image]

Elle a peut-être un lien éloigné et indirect avec les *[go-go dancers](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-go_dancing)*, mais n'en a aucun avec les *[gogos](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gogo)*.

Comment: Bon point pour les _go-go_, possiblement un anglicisme dans mon commentaire de l'autre réponse vs. gogo...

Answer (score 1):

En France, on traduit généralement par :

> Buffet à volonté

Sans spécialement mettre de guillemets.

Comment: Aussi : *à discrétion* (plus soutenu) et *à gogo* (plus familier).

Comment: @jlliagre _À gogo_ je le connais seulement avec _danseuses_... dans le sens de _nues_ je crois. Bon à savoir... Est-ce que c'est dans les deux cas directement avec _buffet_ ou on intercale _en formule_ ? Peut-être ajouter une réponse au besoin...